# sqoop-kafka connector to oracle

Tags: apache-kafka, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to make oracle-kafka connection with [sqoop](/questions/tagged/sqoop). There is a sqoop-kafka connector in this [website](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sqoop.connector/sqoop-connector-kafka), but documentation here is https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.7/user/connectors/Connector-Kafka.html but there is not clean explanation in this documantation and also anywhere. And I am stuck on this problem. I know there are connectors for oracle and kafka but I am trying in this way.

> sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:1521/dbname --username user --password pass --table result --topic testing

```
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --topic
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: test
```

and also I tried this and I also get error

> sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:1521/dbname --username user --password pass --table result --broker-list IP --topic testing

```
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --broker-list
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: testing
```

Comment: I would suggest looking into Kafka Connect rather than Sqoop for this, and I think you are using the wrong Sqoop installation because Sqoop 1.99 is a mostly a re-write that uses a REST API not a CLI

Comment: I know kafka-connect confluent and any other github projects but I am trying in this way, which I wrote in my question. I dont get it what was wrong the sqoop code?

Comment: You're using Sqoop1, not Sqoop2. There is no `sqoop import` for Sqoop2 https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.7/user/Sqoop5MinutesDemo.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer I dont know which sqoop command what to use to send data to kafka topic. Because there is not clear explanation about it. I just write it import.

Comment: The documentation covers it, but it's spread out. That "5 minute tutorial" covers every step though... Start Sqoop2 server. Connect shell to Sqoop2 server. Create a link with connector and job with connector. Start the job. That's it. You use `sqoop2-shell` or the REST API linked in the sidebar

Comment: I know found it from here https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.7/user/Sqoop5MinutesDemo.html but another problem is unfortunately I cant go into sqoop shell. I am using sqoop version 1.4.7-cdh6.3.2.when I write sqoop-shell or sqoop shell command not found @OneCricketeer

Comment: In any case, Kafka Connect binaries are built into your Kafka distribution, so still unclear why you actually want to use Sqoop

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Cloudera doesn't offer Sqoop2

Comment: because my friend. confluent is not open source for multiple kafka brokers, github projects are not realiable and  golden gate is also not open source. I found that sqoop and kafka are from apache and they are open source. and some people made a connector for this. and I want to use it. but I cant.

Comment: how can I enter the shell you any ideas? @OneCricketeer beacuse not found in documentation

Comment: Uh. Compile and install Sqoop2...?

Comment: Kafka Connect as well as JDBC connector are indeed free and open source.

Comment: Speaking of unreliable... Sqoop2 is not actively maintained since around 2017... Confluent Community version is entirely open source and maintained for years since then. Debezium, Nifi, Flink, Streamsets, Spark, etc all can also take data from Oracle to Kafka...

Comment: in confluent community edition for example can I use for free oracle, mssql vs connector and multiple brokers  for production.@OneCricketeer

Comment: You don't need anything Confluent for the brokers, only the connectors for Kafka Connect. So, run Apache Zookeeper and Kafka, which includes Kafka Connect. Then you can use `confluent-hub` to install JDBC Connector, then download all the JDBC drivers you need

Comment: I think you mean this from this website https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/index.html donwload confluent hub and I can download connector and used it free.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add quote to the end of connection string:

> "jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:1521/dbname"

Comment: not problem is not this I can get data from oracle database. the problem is sending data to kafka topic. in my question above

Comment: @newUser Your command is definitely missing a quote, but Sqoop 1.4.6 (the syntax of the command you're using) has no Kafka Connector